# Maven and numerical performance

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project which has a custom machine learning classifier. I am using Surefire plugin for testing my custom library, to check border cases of the classifier and stuff. Now I want to evaluate the performance of the algorithm with some data I have. Is there a Maven plugin, or the best practice to run these "tests" (not unit tests, not integration tests, but performance evaluations)? I mean, I'm looking for being able to do something like

```
mvn test
>> Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
mvn "lets-say-performance-test?"
>> Precision: 0.9, Recall: 0.4, F-score: 0.55
```

I know I could create a non-asserting POJO test with surefire, that just prints the metrics I have, but I would want to know if there is a plugin that does what I want in a more standardized way.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print on the console the result of the performance you can always use the http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ to execute some classes you have and attach it to your build/test phase.

But it might be more judicious to have it run as a real unit test for example to detect abnormal performance values...